# Password migration from laravel 5.0 to laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to migrate a database from Laravel 5.0 to Laravel 5.6, but when I am transferring the `users` table the `password` column does not get passed as it was before (I am assuming Laravel is hashing this again)

> before :- $2y$10$KPCJK7wZ5lHdFMw7y3fchO3qXBvEuqS8wXzvH6vanETH5Pe7CBWVG
>   after :- $2y$10$B7hp5fGX6amcb.CBAnf8TeDxNAxwh5YAxOomi.AEsKfcdf7ovkxTy

I need some way to prevent Laravel from hashing the password. I am doing this to migrate my users table:

```
$user = new User;
$user->password = $request['password'];
$user->save();
```

I was using `User::create()` before but it had the same issue.

I am really confused and stuck and any advice on this will be really helpful.

Comment: So the passwords are already hashed and are getting re-hashed when migrating? You might need to use a raw `DB::table("users")->insert()` statement to prevent the `User` model from Hashing. I'm not sure if you can disable the hashing (I would think you can), but that would be a fallback.

Comment: Yeah Tim it worked.. Thaanks for helping out..you may put it as an answer and I will upvote it and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the `User` model automatically Hashes whatever value is passed into `password`, regardless if it has already Hashed. I'm unsure if there's a direct way to disable this behaviour (likely is, but not sure what `User` is - Basic Laravel Auth, Sentinel, Spatie, etc. etc.), so a workaround is to use the `DB` facade to get around the `User` model:

```
DB::table("users")->insert([
  "password" => $request->input("password"), // or $request["password"]
  ...
]);
```